# Using GDAL.OpenEx() in C# with CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, gdal, ogr

I'm trying to read all fields in a CSV file using GDAL v2.1.3
Using this command it is working:

```
ogrinfo -ro -al -so test.csv -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Lon* -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Lat* -oo KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS=NO
```

Now I need to do this in my C# application.
Because I need to send `-oo` (open options) I cannot use `Ogr.Open()`, but I should use `Gdal.OpenEx()`, right? 
`OpenEx` returns a `Dataset`, which I somehow need to convert to an `ogr datasource` so I can use `GetLayerByIndex()`, `GetFieldCount()` and `GetFieldDefn()` but I can't get it to work.

Looking at numerous Python example it seems in Python no conversion is needed.
This is my C# code:

```
var openOptions = new[]
{
    "X_POSSIBLE_NAMES", "Lon*",
    "Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES", "Lat*",
    "KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS", "NO"
};
using (var ds = Gdal.OpenEx(input, 4, null, openOptions, null))
{
    if (ds == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Can't open OGR dataset: " + input);
    }
    // var layer = ds.GetLayerByIndex(0); <----- COMPILE ERROR
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why am I getting a `-1`? Isn't this a legitimate question? If not please explain why.

Answer (score 0):

I am no swig expert at all, but it looks like the vector (OGR) part of the Dataset is specifically NOT defined for C# in the [current GDAL code](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/75b443c768b9757085c7c0642e575e1417ccf9dd/gdal/swig/include/Dataset.i#L798-L912)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issues with C++, trying to switch from ogr2ogr CLI to GDAL C++. Maybe this will help someone.

I had to format my options array differently to get it to work :

```
  const char *optionsArray[5] = {
    "X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=lon*",
    "Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=lat*",
    "Z_POSSIBLE_NAMES=alt*",
    "KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS=NO",
    NULL
  };
```

In C++ I have to add the ending *NULL* as stated by *GDALOpenEx* [documentation](https://gdal.org/api/raster_c_api.html#_CPPv410GDALOpenExPKcjPPCKcPPCKcPPCKc).